# How do i see Whether The inline ajax validation has been done or not in Jquery

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

Iam using this Form plugin to perfom inline ajax validation and form validation 
http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

I have a textfield say student number for that text field  which will inline validate whether stuno exists or not 
we have 
in the jqueryvalidationengine-en.js

```
"ajaxstudent":{
"file":"student.php",
"alertText":"* SNO is already taken",
"alertTextOk":"", 
"alertTextLoad":"* Checking..."},
$('#submitbutton').click(function(){    
if ($("#form1").validationEngine({returnIsValid:true})) {

}
```

Now my Problem How do i see that inline ajax validation is done before  the form submit.Due to this iam getting Debug error.Iam able to submit the form even when the Student number exists This results in Creation of same Student numbers .How can i overcome this

Comment: please add your inline validation input class definition.

Comment: @Josiah:That is the Definiton in the above

Comment: Any feedback on the answers provided would be nice!

Comment: @zoblib:I tried All the  things But could not Stop it from Submitting

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the validation engine when the page loads. Not when the form is submitted to see inline validation.

```
$(function() { // onready
   $("#formID").validationEngine() // add validation
});
```

Comment: Technically "$(function() {" is onready, not onload, but that's not important for this example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery.ajax complete option

Read here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Use that complete option to enable the submit button, or even better use the success option. You do not take advantage of either option.

I would provide more code but I do not have a lot to work with ;)

Hope this helps at least.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery form validation engine plugin submits the form when it gets some error without validating the fields. Use firebug to find out if there is some javascript error and check the ajax request and response to find out the exact cause.

It works fine if you have configured it properly.

Comment: I  have Checked the firebug Even it is returning False .But it is still Submitting

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the submit button  until you have seen that all the fields have been properly entered, Once this has been validated, edit the attributes of the submit button to make it "clickable"